# Error converting MSG to pdf using pdftron - Python

Tags: python, pdftron

I am trying to convert msg file to pdf using Convert.ToPdf(doc, filename).
The .docx to pdf conversion is done properly using this function, however, I am only getting an error while converting msg to pdf.
The 'print' option is also there in the context menu when I right click on the file.

This is the error I am getting:

> PDFNet is running in demo mode.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 58, in
>  main() File "test.py", line 44, in main Convert.ToPdf(doc,
> filename)
> Exception: An error occurred while converting the file.

> Detailed error: Exception: Message: Unable to find printer Conditional
> expression: success Version : 8.1.0.30521 Platform : Windows
> Architecture : AMD64 Filename : Convert.cpp Function :
> trn::PDF::ToPdfPrinterManager::InitPrinter Linenumber : 776
>
> printing to printer \trial_msg.msg AssocQueryString printto:
> AssocQueryString print : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft
> Office\Root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" /p "" Created new PDFNet Mutex
> WaitForSingleObject start WaitForSingleObject End printo:
> /Local/Temp/pdftron/Trn-17236-1616513476-af5adf11-bd4d-4d40-beec-8f6aad996f18.xps
> Using HKCU Return value for delete registry: 0 Return value for delete
> registry: 0 Return value for release mutex: 0 Return value for close
> mutex: 0 Error destructing ToPdfPrinterManager

Answer (score 0):

The next release of PDFNet, 9.0, will use Outlook interop to do the MSG conversion, instead of the less reliable `printto` command line option.